# How do Spring property placeholder default values work?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

I am going through [this](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.4/#discover-clients-via-spring-cloud-discovery) tutorial and I am not conversant with the following part of the configuration: `defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/`

```
eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
    serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/
```

Why do we have `${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761}` instead of just `http://localhost:8761/eureka/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the author wants to use EUREKA_SERVICE_URL as preferred value. If this is not set, the hardcoded url will be used.

Just remove it if you do not need that.

Maybe you can get more information about property default values [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/).